# Unexpected observation space for CartPole-v0

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm surprised by the observation space I get through introspection for `CartPole-v0`.

According to [the official doc](https://gym.openai.com/docs/#spaces) here's what I should get:

[image]

However here's what I get:

```
print(env.observation_space.low)
print(env.observation_space.high)
#[-4.8000002e+00 -3.4028235e+38 -4.1887903e-01 -3.4028235e+38]
#[4.8000002e+00 3.4028235e+38 4.1887903e-01 3.4028235e+38]
```

I'm using the [latest version of `gym`](https://pypi.org/project/gym/0.7.4/#history):

```
!pip list|grep gym
gym                 0.12.1
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the code, it seems you are obtaining the expected behaviour, which is a little confusing. On the one hand, the observation space is [-4.8, 4.8] for the `cart position`, however, in practice, the episode should finish when the cart reach the limits [-2.4, 2.4]. With the `pole angle` the situation is similar.

```
class CartPoleEnv(gym.Env):
"""
Description:
    A pole is attached by an un-actuated joint to a cart, which moves along a frictionless track. The pendulum starts upright, and the goal is to prevent it from falling over by increasing and reducing the cart's velocity.

Source:
    This environment corresponds to the version of the cart-pole problem described by Barto, Sutton, and Anderson

Observation: 
    Type: Box(4)
    Num Observation                 Min         Max
    0   Cart Position             -4.8            4.8
    1   Cart Velocity             -Inf            Inf
    2   Pole Angle                 -24 deg        24 deg
    3   Pole Velocity At Tip      -Inf            Inf

Actions:
    Type: Discrete(2)
    Num Action
    0   Push cart to the left
    1   Push cart to the right

    Note: The amount the velocity that is reduced or increased is not fixed; it depends on the angle the pole is pointing. This is because the center of gravity of the pole increases the amount of energy needed to move the cart underneath it

Reward:
    Reward is 1 for every step taken, including the termination step

Starting State:
    All observations are assigned a uniform random value in [-0.05..0.05]

Episode Termination:
    Pole Angle is more than 12 degrees
    Cart Position is more than 2.4 (center of the cart reaches the edge of the display)
    Episode length is greater than 200
    Solved Requirements
    Considered solved when the average reward is greater than or equal to 195.0 over 100 consecutive trials.
"""
```

In [this link](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1165) you can read a related Github issue.

*Notice that 24 degrees are equivalent to 4.1887903e-01 radians.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like outdated documentation, an issue has been created: https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/368